# Getting undefined of inner array of JSON response in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngfor

I have below JSON from api

```
 [
  {
    "CinemaId": "Hfsdfsdfs",
    "FilmCode": "HIWdfsdfsfsf47",
    "FilmTitle": "BAfsdfAAR",
    "CinemaName": "CsfsnfsfsAhmedabad",
    "CinemaCity": "Ahmedabad",
    "CinemaLicenseName": "BIGdfsfsAhmedabad",
    "CinemaEmailId": "himfsfsfilms.com",
    "CinemaBannerImg": "F&BCombo.jpg",
    "CinemaAddress": "5fsfdsfsdin Road, 380052, ",
    "CinemaMobile": "93dfsdf17441",
    "CinemaTel": "0",
    "CinemaLocation": "<iframe src=\"fsdfdsdfdsf\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    "Shows": [
      {
        "MovieId": "fsfsfs",
        "CinemaId": "HIWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIdfsfs09847",
        "MovieName": "BAdsfsdfAAR",
        "ScreenName": "SCREEN 4",
        "AvailableSeats": "253",
        "SessionId": "115583",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T14:00:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      },
      {
        "MovieId": "HO000fsdfsd7",
        "CinemaId": "HIWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIWBfsdfs47",
        "MovieName": "BAfsfsR",
        "ScreenName": "SCREEN 4",
        "AvailableSeats": "256",
        "SessionId": "115584",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T16:50:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      },
      {
        "MovieId": "HO0fsdfs9847",
        "CinemaId": "HIfsdfWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIWBHdfsdfsO00009847",
        "MovieName": "BAAZdfsdfsdfAAR",
        "ScreenName": "SCREEN 4",
        "AvailableSeats": "252",
        "SessionId": "115585",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T19:40:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      },
      {
        "MovieId": "HO0fsdfsdf847",
        "CinemaId": "HIWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIfsdfsf9847",
        "MovieName": "BAAZAAR",
        "ScreenName": "SCREEN 4",
        "AvailableSeats": "225",
        "SessionId": "115586",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T22:30:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      },
      {
        "MovieId": "Hdfsdfs47",
        "CinemaId": "HIfsdfsWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIWBHOfsdfsdf00009847",
        "MovieName": "fsfsdf",
        "ScreenName": "EBdsfsdfsUNGE",
        "AvailableSeats": "31",
        "SessionId": "115592",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T21:30:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CinemaId": "HIWB",
    "FilmCode": "fsdfsf",
    "FilmTitle": "dfsfsO",
    "CinemaName": "dfsfsfl, Ahmedabad",
    "CinemaCity": "fsdfs",
    "CinemaLicenseName": "fsdfsfmedabad",
    "CinemaEmailId": "hisdfsfsfilms.com",
    "CinemaBannerImg": "F&BCombo.jpg",
    "CinemaAddress": "dfsfsfin Road, 380052, ",
    "CinemaMobile": "9dsfsf441",
    "CinemaTel": "0",
    "CinemaLocation": "<iframe src=\"dfdfdsfsdf" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    "Shows": [
      {
        "MovieId": "HO00fsfs010556",
        "CinemaId": "HfsfsWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIWBHOfdfsf00010556",
        "MovieName": "BAfsfsfAfsfsfsfAI HO",
        "ScreenName": "SCREEN 1",
        "AvailableSeats": "259",
        "SessionId": "115565",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T15:05:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      },
      {
        "MovieId": "HO00010556",
        "CinemaId": "HIWB",
        "FilmCode": "HIdfsfs10556",
        "MovieName": "BdfsfHO",
        "ScreenName": "SdfsfN 1",
        "AvailableSeats": "249",
        "SessionId": "115568",
        "ShowTime": "2018-10-26T22:45:00",
        "Cast": null,
        "Status": "available"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to show `movieId` and `MovieName` from  `Shows` array

For that I have done below code in ts file

```
getMovies(CinemaId) {
    this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/GetListByCinemaId?CinemaId=' + CinemaId, '').subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.movies = result.Shows;
        console.log(this.movies);
    });
}
```

And In HTML Template Below code is there

```
<select formControlName="cbomovies" id="cbomovies" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedmovies" (change)="OnMoviesChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                    <option value="-1" class="" selected="selected">Select Movie</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let c of movies" [value]="c.MovieId"> {{c.MovieName}} </option>
                  </select>
```

But `this.movies` giving undefined. I also changed in html

```
 <option *ngFor="let c of movies.Shows" [value]="c.MovieId"> {{c.MovieName}} </option>
```

& removed `.Shows` from the `result` in `ts` file. It also giving undefined.

Please help.

Comment: What do you get while you do `console.log(result);` inside `getMovies` function?

Comment: above whole response

Comment: Then notice that it is whole array you get so you cannot do `result.Shows` as `result` is array. So, manage your code accordingly to array data

Comment: That I'm asking how can I manage? I have done above changes but not working

Comment: Your movies is asynchronous , try `<option *ngFor="let c of movies.Shows | async " [value]="c.MovieId"> {{c.MovieName}} </option>` or give `*ngIf="movies"` on `select`

Comment: I believe you have to do two iteration with ngFor. The first should be: `let i of movies`, the second (inside the first) should be `let shows of i` and the you can print your informations

Comment: do you have any method nside the service?

Comment: If you are getting more than one cinema when you call `api/cinemas/GetListByCinemaId?CinemaId=' + CinemaId` something is wrong there.
I'm assuming `CinemaId` should be unique

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal It giving me error in console Cannot read property 'Shows' of undefined

Comment: @mxr7350 Yes it's unique

Comment: Is this json that you get on console.log(this.movies);

Comment: have you initialized your movies array? @SagarKodte

Comment: @SagarKodte your JSON has `array` of 2 `cinema objects` both having CinemaId same, therefore your CinemaId is not unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
this.movies = result.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val.Shows), []);
```

to concat Shows to a single array. Hope this helps.

Comment: Able to access Shows.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of Alex G's answer, I'd like to add that if you're using the Reactive Forms approach, you shouldn't be using `[(ngModel)]` in your template.

Your template will be significantly simplified with just this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  ...
  <select 
    formControlName="cbomovies" 
    id="cbomovies" 
    class="form-control">
    <option value="null" class="">Select Movie</option>
    <option *ngFor="let movie of movies" [value]="movie.MovieId"> {{movie.MovieName}} </option>
  </select>
  ...
</form>
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  movies;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private common: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies('');
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      cbomovies: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  getMovies(CinemaId) {
    this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/GetListByCinemaId?CinemaId=' + CinemaId, '')
    .subscribe((result: any[]) => {
      this.movies = result.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val.Shows), []);
    });
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmsdgm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.